# Curl Returning NULL for LinkedIn Share Count Request

Tags: php, curl, share, linkedin-api

I've set up a plugin for a Wordpress site that I've developed and it uses CURL to get share counts for various social networks.

They all appear to work fine apart from LinkedIn - I'm using the following code to get the count:

```
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=' . $url . '&format=json'
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    $results = json_decode($response);

    curl_close($curl);

    return $results->count;
```

The curious thing is that this works perfectly on my staging server but on live, I get nothing back. I'd have it down as something server related but then the same code works for Facebook.

On my staging server I had to add the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true` line to my code to get it to work but unfortunately it didn't fix it on the live server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to execute comand in bash ...  curl --request GET 'your url'

Comment: Could it be that  LinkedIn blocks Curl requests (to stop bots)? Try setting a custom curl header that imitates a regular browser.

Comment: I am currently having this issue - it is due to the & character and any other non text characters in your url. If you test your URL in a browser it will work, but replace the & with &amp; and you will get a java.lang.NullPointerException 500 error from linked In. It seems Linked In no longer want us to correctly encode our URLs when using their API.

Answer (score 0):

First up make sure that the URL is run through `urlencode`. It'll take care of issues with special characters like `?` and `#`.

You should add error handling code similar to the following after the `curl_exec` call, both for debugging and to provide a fallback when curl errors out.

```
if(curl_errno($curl))
{
    // do something sensible here
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you provide the same value for `$url` on both staging and production: your code seems fine except for the debug/error handling and url encoding. You should check for an outgoing proxy on your live network or broken/old PHP/libcurl versions.

Answer (score 0):

There has been achange to the linkedIn SSL certificates I believe.

You need to set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `false`, so in your exmaple that would be:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=' . $url . '&format=json'
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

$results = json_decode($response);

curl_close($curl);

return $results->count;
```

Normally you would set it as follows:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```